# Bisecting two areas with one line

Tags: geometry

I'm not a mathematician, so please feel free to improve my terminology.

In 2D, I am wondering if it is always possible to bisect two non-intersecting, non-overlapping convex arbitrary shapes with a single line no matter the position or orientation of the shapes.

For example, see the image below.  I want the line to cut the blue shape into two equal pieces.  Same for the red shape.

**It seems pretty obvious to me that this should always be possible, but how would one prove it?**

This question came up while I was cutting slices of garlic bread with a knife.  I cut two pieces at a time to speed up the process.  I have to cut the pieces almost exactly in half so my kids won't argue about who got the most.  :-)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is always possible: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1389985/bisection-theorem

Comment: @Vivianne:  The question and answer in your link seem to only be discussing a SINGLE bounded region.  Again, I'm not a mathematician, so maybe I'm missing its significance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can and this generalizes to $n$-dimensional spaces as well. It's called the [ham sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem) and the two dimensional case is sometimes called the pancake theorem. In two dimensions you can use a "rotating knife" argument using the [Intermediate Value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to ensure the existence of such a cut. Higher dimensional proofs require a bit more machinery but are essentially the same idea.

Comment: Thanks for the ham sandwich theorem link that exactly answers my question!  It's really cool that it works in any number of dimensions.